# How to use angular listener when using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, listener

When I click a button, the controller will get data from some `$http` service callback function and will `$broadcast` it on `$scope`. Then, in the directive, I have a listener to get the data and do some logic. But, when I am using `ng-repeat` on button for several formats, the listener will get fired for all `ng-repeat` items when I click on each button. How can I make the listener to get fired only for the clicked button? Please see the sample code below.

```js
var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    var myCtrl = this;
    myCtrl.getFile = function(){
        var response = 'some data';
  $scope.$broadcast('downloadFile', {'response': response});
 }
});

app.directive('fileDownload', function(){
 return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
   var cancelEvent = scope.$on('downloadFile', function(event, args){
    console.log('called', args);
   });

   scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
    cancelEvent();
   });

  }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as myCtrl">
    <button ng-repeat="format in ['TXT','PDF','CSV']"  ng-click="myCtrl.getFile()" file-download>{{ format }}</button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: actually three instance of directive exist so it is calling three times can let me know what you want to trying to do ?

Comment: I want to download files using attribute directive when placed on a button. The button is bound to `ng-click` controller method which uses a `$http` request to fetch file's data and then the data will be processed by directive to be displayed. I know there are three instances of the directive and that's why the data is being processed by directive three times. My question is how to make the directive to process data only once for the clicked item?

Answer (score 0):

> In this sample you can figure out how can create directive using scope, i create a sample to get all formats **get all lists**, **get checked list**, **get download format**, on directive.
>
> About your codes, actually response is true, because when we use some functions like **[$broadcast]** or ... on app run all data already sets in our scopes. but remember in this case you don't need to use $broadcast that because our actions are in-time and we can get them when we click on a function.

*hope helps you my friend*

```js
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

        app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
            var self = this;

            self.lists = [
                { name: "A"},
                { name: "B"},
                { name: "C"},
                { name: "D"}
            ];

            self.getFile = function () {
                console.log('controller', "done");
            }
        });

        app.directive('fileDownload', function ($filter) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    fileDownload: "=",
                    list: "="
                },
                link: function (scope, elem) {
                    elem.on("click", function () {
                        var filter = $filter("filter")(scope.list, { checked: true });
                        console.log('from directive, all list', scope.list);
                        console.log('from directive, checked list', filter);
                        console.log('from directive, download format', scope.fileDownload);
                    });
                }
            }

        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as self">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <small>list</small>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="list in self.lists">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="list.checked"/>
            {{list.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>

    <small>download format</small>
    <button ng-repeat="format in ['TXT','PDF','CSV']" ng-click="self.getFile()" list="self.lists" file-download="format">{{ format }}</button>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Maher! But, the data from controller will be set only after `$http` request is resolved. So, the actions are not actually in time. After click event, the data might be empty or null in directive. Any suggestion how to tackle that?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
        <div ng-app="demoApp">
            <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as myCtrl">
                <span ng-repeat="format in ['TXT','PDF','CSV']">
                  <span get-file="myCtrl.getFile({data: data})" file-download title="format"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);

        app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
            var myCtrl = this;
            myCtrl.getFile = function(data) {
                var response = 'some data';
                console.log(response);
                console.log(data);
                // $scope.$broadcast('downloadFile', {'response': response});
            }

        });

        app.directive('fileDownload', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                template: "<button ng-click='callFn()'>{{title}}</button>",
                scope: {
                  title: '=',
                  getFile: '&'
                },
                link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                  scope.callFn = function(){
                    scope.getFile({data: scope.title});
                  }
                    // var cancelEvent = scope.$on('downloadFile', function(event, args) {
                    //     console.log('called', args);
                    // });

                    // scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                    //     cancelEvent();
                    // });

                }
            }

        });
    </script>
</html>
```